# How to make fetch_related work on class-based View?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I really like the CBV approach but can't seem to make it work in this case. `Team` and `Person` models are connected by the `players` M2M relation through the `Player` model.

```
class Person(Model):
    last_name = CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
class Team(Model):
    players = ManyToManyField(Person, through='Player')
    ...
class Player(Model):
    person = ForeignKey(Person)
    team = ForeignKey(Team)
    date_joined = DateField()
    ...
```

A team roster with names and date_joined on the team detail page makes one query per player, so I prefetch player data:

```
def team_detail_view(request, pk=None):
    ...
    team = Team.objects.get(pk=pk)
    roster = team.player_set.all().prefetch_related('person')
    return render_to_response('team_detail.html', 
        {'object': team, 'roster': roster}, ...)
```

How to make a CBV use prefetch_related? I've found the `PrefetchRelatedMixin` in django-braces, but when I do

```
class TeamDetailView(PrefetchRelatedMixin, DetailView):
    prefetch_related = [u'players']
    model = Team
```

this still gives a separate query for each player in the template

```
{% for player in object.player_set %}
<tr><td>{{ player.person.last_name }}</td><td>{{ player.date_joined }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Seems that what is needed is a way to call `prefetch_related` on the M2M field of the Team model, not on the team itself. Can it be accomplished using CBV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that

```
class TeamDetailView(PrefetchRelatedMixin, DetailView):
    prefetch_related = ['player_set__person']
    model = Team
```

does the trick, though I'm not completely sure about the mechanics of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding get_queryset()?

```
class TeamDetailView(DetailView):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.prefetch_related('players').all()
```

Answer (score 0):

DetailView operates on self.get() not self.get_queryset() where your Mixin overloads. You would have to modify PrefetchRelatedMixin to support your prefetch_related attribute on get().